# Problem with Python encrypted request.post

Tags: python-3.x, api, post

I have a problem with encrypted post requests. The encrypted algorithm is AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding and API settings are here: https://bondevalue.com/app/apiInstructions client_token is working. But I always receive 'Seems you are providing invalid input data. Provide data in valid format.'

```
import requests
import json
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import base64

client_token = b'ae3rncr14cngemft'
requestData = b'{\"data\":{\"userToken\":\"[ae3rncr14cngemft]\"},\"bondISINId\":\"[XS1401197253]\", \"fromDate\":\"[2016-12-07]\"}'
cipher1 = AES.new(client_token, AES.MODE_ECB)
requestEncrypted = str(base64.b64encode(cipher1.encrypt(pad(requestData, 16, 'pkcs7'))), 'utf-8')

url = 'https://bondevalue.com/app/bondDetailsHistoryData'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = {'requestData': requestEncrypted}

answer = requests.post(url=url, data=requestEncrypted, headers=headers)
response = answer.json()
```

Comment: The link you provided for the API requires registration. See if you can find a public link to the documentation or provide one yourself via a public site.

Comment: You shouldn't include your personal api key in the code. Perhaps replace it with 'my_api_key' or '<api_key>'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Here is my working api key. I will change it after solving the problem.

Comment: I suppose the problem is in data. I tried a lot of variations.